# Sequences of functions Uniform Convergence Question

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let g and h be positive and continuous on $[a,b]$ and define $f_n(x):=\frac{ng(x)}{1+n^2h(x)}$. Prove $n\sin{(f_{n})}\rightarrow\frac{g}{h}$ uniformly on $[a,b]$

Comment: You write $nsin(f_n)$?

Comment: Yes, i think so thanks for prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

We will use the $sin$ series. So we have $nsin(f_n(x))=n\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\cdot (\frac {ng(x)}{1+n^2h(x)})^{2k+1}$ For $k=0$ we have the term $\frac {n^2g(x)}{1+n^2h(x)}\to \frac {g(x)}{h(x)}$ and all the other terms go to $0$.

Now you have to show that $\| nsin(f_n(x))-\frac {g(x)}{h(x)}\|_{\infty}\to 0$. You can try from here.

Comment: for k=0, the top of term is not n square just n right?

Comment: No, it's $n^2g(x)$

Comment: right! i omitted the n which is outside of summation. why we can do the analysis under k=0? I don't really get it

Comment: Yes because the other terms go to $0$ due to the bottom of the fraction which will be bigger from the top.Good luck now,i have to go to sleep.Write if you need more info,i'll answer tomorrow

Comment: thanks! have a good night!